# How to get int value from one method to another

Tags: java, android, listview, count, int

I need to carry my int value from one method to another, but I didnt find any solution. One method counts number of objects and the number needs to be "delivered" to another and check, if the count equals to something.

Do you have any idea, how to do it?

Check my codes below:

```
@Override
protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
    ParseQuery<Animal> query = ParseQuery.getQuery(Animal.class);
    query.countInBackground(callcount = new CountCallback(){
        public void done(int count, ParseException e) {
            if (e == null) {
                Log.v("count is" + count, "count is");                           
                //I need to export int count from "done" method to another                
            } else {
            }
        }
    }); 
}
```

And the secont method, which has to recieve that value and use it:

```
@Override
public void onScrollStateChanged(AbsListView view, int scrollState) {
    //i need to set int count from method above here
    int threshold = 1;
    int counter = mListView.getCount();

    if (scrollState == SCROLL_STATE_IDLE) {

    if (mListView.getLastVisiblePosition() >= counter - threshold) {
        updateData();                   
    }
}
```

Whole code:

```
public class Fragment1 extends Fragment {
    static ListView mListView;
    static AnimalAdapter mAdapter;
    static ProgressBar mProgressBar;
    static EditText mEditText;
    static LayoutInflater inflater;
    CountCallback callcount;
    int g_count = 0;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        final View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.animalsfrag, container, false);
        mListView = (ListView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.animal_list);

        View header = getActivity().getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.header, null);

        header.setPadding(2, 8, 4, 2);
        mListView.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        mListView.requestFocus();
        mListView.addHeaderView(header); 

        View footie = getActivity().getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.footer, null);
        mListView.addFooterView(footie);
        footie.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);


        mProgressBar = (ProgressBar) rootView.findViewById (R.id.loading_animals);
        mProgressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

        RemoteDataTask task = new RemoteDataTask();
        task.execute();




        return rootView;
    }



    public void updateData() {
         mListView = (ListView)getView().findViewById(R.id.animal_list);     
   final ParseQuery<Animal> query = ParseQuery.getQuery(Animal.class);
    query.setCachePolicy(CachePolicy.NETWORK_ONLY);
    query.orderByAscending("animal");
    query.setLimit(mListView.getCount() + 5);

    Log.v("updateData", "uploading data from Parse.com");
    query.findInBackground(new FindCallback<Animal>() {

        @Override
          public void done(List<Animal> animals, ParseException error) {

              if(animals != null){
                mAdapter.clear();
                mProgressBar = (ProgressBar) getView().findViewById (R.id.loading_animals);
               mProgressBar.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
             RelativeLayout footie = (RelativeLayout) getView().findViewById(R.id.footerview);  
            footie.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

              mAdapter.clear();
            for (int i = 0; i < animals.size(); i++) {

                      mAdapter.add(animals.get(i));

                    }  

              }  
            }
         }); }






     private class RemoteDataTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {



         @Override
            protected void onPreExecute() {
                super.onPreExecute();  }

         @Override
            protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {

                return null;



         }


         @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
             ParseQuery<Animal> query = ParseQuery.getQuery(Animal.class);
             query.countInBackground(callcount = new CountCallback(){
                 public void done(int count, ParseException e) {
                        if (e == null) {
                            Log.v("count is" + count, "count is");
                         if (mListView.getCount() == count) {
                             Log.v("all loaded", "executed");
                             g_count=count;
                         }
                        } else {
                          // The request failed
                        }
                      }
                    }); 

                Log.v("onpostexecute", "executing");
               mListView = (ListView) getView().findViewById(R.id.animal_list);
               if(mListView.getCount() == 0){
                    updateData();

                }


               mEditText = (EditText) getView().findViewById(R.id.search_animal);

               mAdapter = new AnimalAdapter(getActivity(), new ArrayList<Animal>());

               mListView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
               mListView.setTextFilterEnabled(true);
               mListView.setAdapter(mAdapter);




               mListView.setOnScrollListener(new OnScrollListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onScroll(AbsListView view, int firstVisibleItem, int visibleItemCount,
                            int totalItemCount) {
                    }


                    @Override
                    public void onScrollStateChanged(AbsListView view,
                            int scrollState) {

                        int threshold = 1;
                        int counter = mListView.getCount();

                        if (scrollState == SCROLL_STATE_IDLE) {

                            if (mListView.getLastVisiblePosition() >= counter
                                    - threshold){

                                updateData();

                                Log.v("count", "count is" + g_count);

                                }
                            }


                        if (SCROLL_STATE_TOUCH_SCROLL == scrollState) {
                            View currentFocus = getActivity().getCurrentFocus();
                            if(currentFocus != null) {
                                currentFocus.clearFocus();
                            }
                        }



                    }

                });


                mEditText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher(){

                    @Override
                    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {}

                    @Override
                    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s,
                            int start, int count, int after) {}

                    @Override
                    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start,
                            int before, int count) {

                        System.out.println("Text ["+s+"]");
                        mAdapter.getFilter().filter(s.toString());  
                        }
                });

               }

            }
         }
```

I'd be glad for any advice.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are not calling function from another then you need to create a global variable.
Declare a variable just after your class declaration i.e.

```
int g_count = 0;
```

then in

```
 public void done(int count, ParseException e) {
                    if (e == null) {
                        Log.v("count is" + count, "count is");
                        g_count=count;
                     }
```

Then in second fucntion

```
public void onScrollStateChanged(AbsListView view, int scrollState) {
int count=g_count; \\you dont really need to declare this, just use g_count
int threshold = 1;
int counter = mListView.getCount();

if (scrollState == SCROLL_STATE_IDLE) {

if (mListView.getLastVisiblePosition() >= counter - threshold) {
    updateData();                   
}
}
```

Comment: Thanks for an answer! and what do I have to do in my second method? Ive tried it like this, but the g_count is 0 in second activity.

Comment: for second method just use as it is
`
public void onScrollStateChanged(AbsListView view, int scrollState) {
int count=g_count; \\use this count everywhere
 }`

Comment: when i use it in onScrollStateChanged it returns 0, not the real count from method above

Comment: then it means onScrollStateChanged is called before done method, debug it to verify. If it is then I will need to see your complete code.

Comment: Im sure, that done method is called before. Check the edit, ive uploaded the code

Comment: You are using wrong logic, you will not get a value until done is called because onscrollstatechanged in called everytime you scroll the list but you are saying a value when the data is uploaded and onPostexecute, so until it is executed you cant get the value. One solution that you can use it to use TimerTask. Save value of count after every few seconds